# calling a component function from another component using angular 4 ng-smarttable

Tags: angular

I am using ng-smarttable for rendering the data in a table and i have implemented the custom button in another component. And i want to reload the data once click on the button.

I am getting the error saying, `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'showData' of undefined`

I have added the code in `stackblitz.com`. Can anyone help on this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/smarttable-dtgk61?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: do you want to pass parent data to child?

Comment: @chellappan, I want to reload the table after clicking the button. i am able to emit the event and inside calling the reload function. can you tell how to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the method showData static and access it via AppComponent.showData() instead of this.showData().

Comment: I am reloading the table content after clicking on the button. This method will call one common service where  i am fetching the data from server and returning. Can you please tell how to call the method without 'static' keyword